# C++ how to convert string to char array and check for digits?

Tags: c++

how do I do this? i want it to check for numbers

```
cout<<"Enter your first number: ";
std::cin >> dblNumOne;
int i=0;
char str[]=dblNumkOne;
while (str[i])
{
    if (isalpha(str[i])) printf ("character %c is alphabetic\n",str[i]);
    else printf ("character %c is not alphabetic\n",str[i]);
    i++;
}
```

Comment: Why don't you just iterate through the string instead of trying to convert it?

Answer (score 2):

Simple, just iterate through the std::string as such:

```
std::string dblNumOne;
std::cin >> dblNumOne;

for(unsigned int i = 0; i < dblNumOne.length(); i++)
{
    if (isalpha(dblNumOne[i]))
    {
        printf ("character %c is alphabetic\n", dblNumOne[i]);
    }
    else
    {
        printf ("character %c is not alphabetic\n", dblNumOne[i]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use string instead of char, because string has a `length` function

so like this:

```
std::string dblNumOne;
std::cout<<"Enter your first number: ";
std::cin >> dblNumOne;
std::cout << dblNumOne.length() << endl;
```

If you have to use char, then you can simply do it by checking `'\0'` value which stands for end of string.

My approach would be use the string and get the length of it and then convert it to char array by using `c_str()` function.

Answer (score 0):

1) Convert the string to a char array:

```
strcpy(charArray,stringArray.c_str());
```

Source: http://v2.cplusplus.com/forum/windows/71633/

2) Print out whether it's a digit or not using `isdigit`:

```
while (charArray[i]) {
    if (isdigit(charArray[i])){
        printf ("character %c is a digit\n",str[i]);
    } else {
        printf ("character %c is not a digit\n",str[i]);
    }
    i++;
}
```

Remember to click the grey check mark (the ✓) to the left of my answer if it answers your question or led you to the answer!

Comment: It's simpler than writing a `for` loop and manually putting each char into the array one-by-one, but that should work too.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the original `std::string` - one can iterate over its charachters and do whaever he wants.

Comment: Don't reinvent the wheel

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check for numbers, you could try this:

```
std::string str = "";
std::cout<<"enter string>>";
std::cin>>str;

int is_number = 0; 
char filter[] = "0123456789";

for(int n=0; n<str.size(); ++n){
   for(int i=0; i<10; ++i){

      if(str[n] == filter[i]){
          ++is_number;
          break; // found match, filter next char in str
      }else if(str[n] != filter[i] && i == 9){
          std::cout<<"'"<<str[n]<<"' is not a digit!\n";
      }
   }
}

if(is_number == str.size()){
    std::cout<<"You entered a number";
}else std::cout<<"You didn't enter a number!";
```

or to recognize decimal numbers you could try this:

```
int is_number = 0, is_decimal = 0; 
char filter[] = ".0123456789";

for(int n=0; n<str.size(); ++n){
   for(int i=0; i<11; ++i){

      if(str[n] == filter[i]){
          if(filter[i] == '.'){
            ++is_decimal;
          }
          ++is_number;
          break;
      }
   }
}// for decimal

if(is_number == str.size() && is_decimal <= 1){
    std::cout<<"You entered a number";
}else std::cout<<"You didn't enter a number!";
```